# Initializing struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, allocation

OK, this is the definition of the struct:

```
typedef struct {
   int first;
   int last;
   int count;
   char * Array [50];
} queue;
```

and I use another function to initialize it

```
void initialize(queue * ptr){
   ptr=malloc(sizeof(queue));
   ptr->first=0;
   ptr->last=0;
   ptr->count=0;
}
```

Then I use printf to print out first, last and count. All three should be zero. However, what I actually get is, count is 0 as I expected, but first&last are two very large strange numbers and they change every time I run the program. Can anybody tell me what's wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: How are you calling your function? Can you post the code for that too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing your pointer *by value*. The function changes a *copy* of the argument it receives, but the caller's pointer is not modified and is probably unintialized.

You need to change your function to take a `queue**` and pass the address of the pointer you want to initialize.

Alternatively you could return a pointer instead of passing it in as an argument. This is a simpler approach.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
void initialize(queue * ptr);
```

Pass it like this:

```
queue q; // caller allocates a queue
initialize(&q);
// now q is initialized
```

Also, it's allocated by the caller -- don't malloc it.

```
// bad
void initialize_bad(queue * ptr){
   ptr=malloc(sizeof(queue)); << nope. already created by the caller. this is a leak
   ptr->first=0;
   ptr->last=0;
   ptr->count=0;
}

// good
void initialize_good(queue * ptr){
   ptr->first=0;
   ptr->last=0;
   ptr->count=0;
   // ptr->Array= ???;
}
```

If you prefer to malloc it, then consider returning a new allocation by using this approach:

```
queue* NewQueue() {
   // calloc actually works in this case:
   queue* ptr = (queue*)calloc(1, sizeof(queue));
   // init here
   return ptr;
}
```

Ultimately, what is 'wrong' is that your implementation passes a pointer by value, immediately reassigns the pointer to a new malloc'ed allocation, initializes the malloc'ed region as desired, without ever modifying the argument, and introducing a leak.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the smallest alteration to your program which should correct your problem:

```
void initialize(queue * * pptr) {
    queue * ptr;
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(queue));
    if (ptr) {
        ptr->first=0;
        ptr->last=0;
        ptr->count=0;
    }
    /* The assignment on the next line assigns the newly allocated pointer
       into memory which the caller can access -- because the caller gave
       us the address of (i.e. pointer to) such memory in the parameter
       pptr. */
    *pptr = ptr;
}
```

The most important change is to pass a `queue **` to your initialize function -- otherwise you are changing a *copy* of the `queue *` supplied as the actual parameter when you call `initialize()`.  By passing a pointer to the pointer, you can access the original variable which stores the pointer in your caller.

I couldn't resist and also added a check for `NULL` returned from `malloc()`.  That doesn't address your problem, but I couldn't bring myself to post code that didn't do it.